# How do I set a cookie to be used on all calls to the Worklight Server from a Native Android App

Tags: android, cookies, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm building an native Android app with Worklight 6.0.0.1 and having trouble connecting to our production Worklight Server.

The server is fronted by a DataPower appliance that handles authentication and requires us to send a particular cookie on any call to the Worklight Server.

We tried using addGlobalHeader("Cookie", "cookie-name=cookievalue") to set this cookie, but found that using this API does not play nicely with the cookies that Worklight itself uses to manage it's session.

The cookie header is properly set for the initial request to Worklight, and Worklight responds with a challenge and sets JSESSIONID and WL_PERSISTENT_COOKIE.

Then, when the Android API answers this challenge we see 2 cookie headers being sent in the follow-up request which violates norms for http headers. 
Cookie:  JSESSIONID=<...>;WL_PERSISTENT_COOKIE=<...>
Cookie:

Oddly, if I go through a TCPMon proxy to inspect the traffic, I can connect successfully, but if I go directly against the DataPower address, it doesn't see the header and fails to reach Worklight.

What is the correct way to inject a cookie so my cookie goes into a single cookie header along with all of the other cookies that Worklight wants?

Answer (score 0):

Add global header will add headers, it was not designed for cookies. If you need to set cookies I'd suggest trying Android's CookieStore. Create you cookie with all the relevant params (value/url/expiry etc) and add it to CookieStore

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/CookieStore.html

Comment: will CookieStore set cookie for all the requests that are sent internally by work light? The DefaultHttpClient instance used by worklight internally is different then what we'll use for CookieStore